# How to design and implement ES6 Set without calling the API new Set()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

I was asked a question how to implement a Set in javascript, specifically how to design a class that emulates a Set in ES6. What should the underlying data structure be?

Comment: [An object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects)

Comment: @JaromandaX I'd think an array because the keys would need to be of arbitrary type, not just strings. Of course the object could contain the keys as property values I guess (like an array)

Comment: What did you try? Not too many choices to work with

Comment: A simple search for *javascript Set polyfill' turns up several results including https://github.com/jfriend00/ES6-Set and https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim

Comment: Was the question specifically without using an instance of `Set`? Because then it's trivial to implement by using a `Map` instead and just ignoring the values.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a `Map`:

```
class Set {
    constructor(items) {
        this._map = new Map(Array.from(items, [v, true]));
    }

    get size() { 
        return this._map.size;
    }

    has(v) {
        this._map.has(v);
    }
    add(v) {
        this._map.set(v, true);
    }
    delete(v) {
        this._map.delete(v);
    }
    clear() {
        this._map.clear();
    }

    *entries() {
        for (const k of this._map.keys()) {
            yield [k, k];
        }
    }

    keys() {
        return this._map.keys();
    }
    values() {
        return this._map.keys();
    }
    forEach(cb, context) {
        for (const k of this._map.keys()) {
            cb.apply(context, k, k);
        }
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return this.values();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer! can we use object instead?

Comment: @ZhenghaoHe There are polyfills, you can always look at something like https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/blob/master/es6-shim.js#L3219.